# Конвертирование изображений в .png при помощи php

Tags: php, изображения, png, функции

Хочу, чтобы на сайт загружались картинки и при загрузке они конвертировались в формат .png. Есть какие-нибудь функции для этого? Может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: [Например это](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm) вызывать не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно я (будучи зеленым) искал подходящие классы с просто большим количеством кода - и использованием в 2-3 строчки..
примерами служат..
[Imagine](http://www.slideshare.net/avalanche123/introduction-toimagine)
[WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)
[SimpleImage](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/the-simple-image-class-for-php/)
[Kohana Image](http://blogocms.ru/2011/04/kohana-modul-image/)

Именно такими инструментами я пользовался, когда занимался изменением, перерисовкой, рендерингом загружаемых клиентами файлов